# In R, I want to insert values in one column in one dataframe based on the values in three other columns over two dataframes

Tags: r, if-statement, mutate

I am working with two dataframes, each with multiple columns. One dataframe, called "offenses", contains data on crimes across the U.S. One variable is "V3", which is a code given to every law enforcement agency that reports data. Another dataframe, called "crosswalk", contains data on codes used in many different governmental datasets. It has two relevant codes: "ORI7", which is the same as "V3" and "FIPS" which is a code referencing various counties in the U.S.

There are many more "V3" observations than there are "FIPS" codes, because each county may have multiple law enforcement agencies operating within it. For example, in Cook County, Illinois, there is only one FIPS code (because there's only one county), but there are dozens of "ORI7" and "V3" codes, because there are dozens of law enforcement agencies operating in Cook County.

I have created a column in "offenses" called "fips", and I want to import the "FIPS" codes from the "crosswalk" dataframe into this column, such that I have the appropriate ORI7/V3 code and the fips/FIPS code in the "offenses" dataframe. I can then analyze crimes at the county level, which is my research aim, without having to repeatedly reference the "crosswalk" dataframe (nothing else in "crosswalk" is relevant to me).

I've made these attempts, but of course they don't work:

```
offenses2 <- offenses |>
  mutate(fips = ifelse(offenses$V3 == crosswalk$ORI7, crosswalk$FIPS, NA)

offenses$fips[offenses$fips == "TEST"] <- ifelse(offenses$V3 == crosswalk$ORI7, crosswalk$FIPS, NA)
```

For the latter, I got this error message:

> Error in Ops.factor(offenses$V3, crosswalk$ORI7) :    level sets of
> factors are different

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your first attempt, change `==` to `%in%`. When using `==`, it is testing whether offenses$V3 and crosswalk$ORI7 are identical. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1: `merge`/`join`

`merge`is your friend, or, since you are using `dplyr` anyway, the `*_join` functions. E.g.

```
offenses2 <-
  left_join(offenses,
            crosswalk |> select(ORI7, FIPS),
            by = c(V3 = "ORI7"))
```

The `by` clause specifies how the columns are matched. In the statement above `V3` on the `offenses` table (the first argument of the `_join`, so it is on the LHS of the clause), is matched to the `ORI7` column of the `crosswalk` table (second argument of the `_join`, so on the RHS of the `by` clause).

We `select` the columns we want from the `crosswalk`, otherwise all other columns on it would be merged.  You'll always want to select the column(s) that will be matched + the columns you want to merge.

Check the help for `left_join` (and `full_join`, `inner_join`, `anti_join`, etc, while you're at it) for details.

#### Method 2: `match`

For this particular case, of using a second table as a "dictionary" of sorts, to bring matching values from a single column onto a different table, using `match` is usually much faster:

```
offenses$FIPS <- crosswalk$FIPS[match(offenses$V3, crosswalk$ORI7)]
```

Comment: Method 1 worked perfectly (I didn't need to try method 2)! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you please mark the answer as 'Accepted', then? Thanks